# 'module' object has no attribute 'message_all'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem.
I have 2 files, `asd` and `csd`.

`asd` code:

```
def aaa()
  print("test")
```

`csd` code:

```
import asd
asd.aaa()
```

I run `python csd.py` and it shows an error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'aaa'
```

The actual module I'm importing from is [`zxlolbot.py`](https://github.com/Mathzx/zxLoLBoT/blob/master/zxlolbot.py); I am trying to use:

```
import zxlolbot

zxlolbot.message_all('some message')
```

Comment: You appear to be importing a different module. What does `import asd; print(asd)` show is being imported?

Comment: Will you please try `print asd` after import ?

Comment: @Lafada: Python 3; `print()` is a function there.

Comment: pls use basic english :D :D :D

Comment: @MartijnPieters asd = zxlolbot.py 

import zxlolbot;print(zxlolbot)
=
<module 'zxlolbot' from '/root/bot/v1/zxlolbot.py'>

Comment: @Buğraİşgüzar: and `zxlolbot.py` actually has the right function defined? You didn't accidentally make a typographical error?

Comment: @MartijnPieters see pls: http://i.imgur.com/sVN5RNb.png

zxlolbot code: https://github.com/Mathzx/zxLoLBoT/blob/master/zxlolbot.py

Comment: @Buğraİşgüzar what function is throwing the exception?

Comment: @MartijnPieters message_all

Comment: @Buğraİşgüzar: that's not a top-level function. `message_all()` is a *method* on the `zxLoLBoT` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no top-level `zxlolbot.message_all()` function here. You are trying to use a *method*, defined for the `zxLoLBoT` class.

You'll need to create an instance of the class, then call the method on that; according to the [`zxLolBot` documentation](https://github.com/Mathzx/zxLoLBoT/) you are actually supposed to *subclass* that class to implement your own bots:

```
import zxlolbot


class Example(zxlolbot.zxLoLBoT):    
    @zxlolbot.botcommand
    def hello(self, sender, args):
        """Say hello to everyone"""
        self.message_all("hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = Example("username", "password")
    bot.connect()
```

Here the example bot has been given a command method, 'hello', that when called will send the text 'hello' to everyone.

Methods like `message_all` appear to be designed to help you write such bots, not call them from 'outside'.

Comment: im fixed problem but very thx @martijn ^^